# Getting 'Bad Request' Error when Adding Side Pages to Menu - Apache Server Issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, sidebar, bad-request, port80

I've encountered a puzzling issue while attempting to add more side pages to the menu on my website. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

**Bad Request**

**Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.**

**Apache/2.4.57 (Debian) Server at server.server.cz Port 80**

This issue has left me scratching my head, as it seems to be related to the server configuration. I'm running Apache 2.4.57 on a Debian-based server, and I'm not quite sure how to troubleshoot this "Bad Request" error.

Here are some details about my setup:

Can someone shed some light on what could be causing this error and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any insights or tips would be greatly appreciated!